# Excluding certain punctuation symbols from being returned by ispunct() in C

Tags: c

I am making a program in C that finds out the number of sentences in a string by searching for punctuation marks. I am using ispunct() to find punctuation. However, it is not just returning the number of periods, question marks, and exclamation points like I want it to. It is also returning commas and every other symbol that is not alphanumeric. So this sentence:

"Hello! I go by the names Peter, Iscreamyay, nerdinuity, and GameProgrammerGalaxy."

Is said, according to the program, to have SIX Sentences!

I was wondering if there was a way to exclude certain punctuation symbols from being returned in ispunct() Here is the section of code that finds this currently:

```
int main(void){
char text[100];
int letterNum = 0;
int wordNum = 0;
int sentenceNum = 0;
printf("Text: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", text);
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++){
    if(isalpha(text[i])){
        letterNum++;
    }
    if(isspace(text[i])){
        wordNum++;
    }
    if(ispunct(text[i])){
        sentenceNum++;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to check a fixed set of values, use `strchr`

Comment: Simplest is just to use a table lookup for the chars that you want to recognize.

Comment: [man strchr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

Comment: Thank you guys! I actually already found the answer to this question. It meant a lot that you guys answered this question so fast!